# How to keep checkboxes selected and count after navigating to another page in using a select all function - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a react app that contains a table that is populated with records from Django through rest-API. The app have a function that can select all checkboxes of each record from the table using a main checkbox in the header.

I am looking if it is possible to keep the checkboxes checked and keep the count after navigating to another page.

Here are the snippets for selectAllHandler, selectOnHandler and the selected counter which counts the number of checkboxes selected.

```
const selectAllHandler = (e) => {
    const toggleAll = e.target.checked;
    const updatedCheckBoxes = {};
    const newCheckBoxes = {};

    accounts.forEach((account) => {
      updatedCheckBoxes[`ch${account.id}-${account.compliant}`] = toggleAll;
    });
  
    setCheckBoxes(updatedCheckBoxes);

    for (let cbox in checkBoxes) {
      newCheckBoxes[cbox] = toggleAll;
    }
    setCheckBoxes(newCheckBoxes);
    setSelectAll(toggleAll)
  };

const selectOneHandler = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.checked;
    const name = target.name;

    const newCheckBoxes = { ...checkBoxes, [name]: value };
    const toggleAll = Object.values(newCheckBoxes).every((chk) => chk);

    const someChecked = Object.values(newCheckBoxes).some((chk) => chk);

    setCheckBoxes(newCheckBoxes);
    setSelectAll(toggleAll || (someChecked && !value));
  };

  const selectedCount = Object.values(checkBoxes).filter(Boolean).length;
```

Here is how the records are populated

```
const getAccount = async () => {
    
    const data = await axios
    .get("accounts/api/get-accounts/", {
      params: {
        page: pageParam,
        order: order,
        field: fieldOrder,
        search_field: searchField,
        search_value: searchValue,
        filter_type: getAccountType(),
        page_size: pageSize,
        compliant: compSel,
        privileged: classSel,
        enabled: enSel,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setAccounts(res.data.accounts);
      setCheckBoxes(res.data.accounts.reduce((acc, d) => ((acc["ch" + d.id + "-" + d.compliant] = false), acc), {}));
      setSelectAll(false);
      setPages(res.data.pages);
      setPage(res.data.page);
      setCount(res.data.count);
    }); 
    setLoading(true);
  }
```

Sharing also the table

```
<Table hover className="mb-0">
  <thead style={{ 
          position:'sticky',
          top: '0px',
          borderBottom: '1px solid #000',
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        }}>
    <tr style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
      {!user.group.includes('Users_RO') &&
        <th>
          <Input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={!!selectAll}
            onChange={(e) => selectAllHandler(e)}
            style={{ display: "flex" }}
          />
        </th>
      }
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('account')}>Account Name {renderSortArrow('account')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('host')}>Account Host {renderSortArrow('host')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('type')}>Account Type {renderSortArrow('type')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('enabled')}>Account Enabled {renderSortArrow('enabled')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('privileged')}>Account Classification {renderSortArrow('privileged')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('last_scanned')}>Last Scanned {renderSortArrow('last_scanned')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('compliant')}>Compliant {renderSortArrow('compliant')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('compliance_reason')}>Compliance Reason {renderSortArrow('compliance_reason')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('account_owner')}>Account Owner {renderSortArrow('account_owner')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('exception_link')}>Account Level Exception {renderSortArrow('exception_link')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('exception_type')}>Exception Type {renderSortArrow('exception_type')}</th>
      <th onClick={() => toggleSort('comment')}>Comment {renderSortArrow('comment')}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {accounts.map((account) => (
      <tr style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis' }} key={account.id}>
        {!user.group.includes('Users_RO') &&
          <td>
            <Input
              type="checkbox"
              id={account.id + "-" + (account.compliant ? 'True' : 'False')}
              name={"ch" + account.id + "-" + account.compliant}
              checked={!!checkBoxes["ch" + account.id + "-" + account.compliant]}
              onChange={(e) => selectOneHandler(e)}
              style={{ display: "flex" }}
            />
          </td>
        }
        <td>{account.account}</td>
        <td>{account.host}</td>
        <td>{account.type}</td>
        <td>{account.enabled ? 'True' : 'False' }</td>
        <td>{account.account_classification}</td>
        <td>{account.last_scanned}</td>
        {account.account_classification==='Privileged' ?
          <td style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            {account.compliant ? (
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faCheckCircle}
                size="lg"
                className="text-success mx-1"
              />
            ) : (
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faXmarkCircle}
                size="lg"
                className="text-danger mx-1"
              />
            )}
          </td> : <td>{""}</td>}
        <td>{account.compliance_reason}</td>
        <td>{account.account_owner}</td>
        <td>{account.exception_link}</td>
        <td>{account.exception_type}</td>
        <td>{account.comment}</td>
        
      </tr>
      ))}
  </tbody>
</Table> :                           
<div>{[...Array(3)].map((x,i)=>
    <Spinner key={i} type='grow' style={{width: "1.5rem",height: "1.5rem", margin:'2px'}} color="primary"/>
  )}
</div>
}
```